# How to refactor member function that only differs in string printed

Tags: c++

I'm coding a Old Gameserver just to learn more about c++ and Reverse engineering.
I'm also studying about code refactoring and design patterns.

Currently I have this member functions :

```
void CommandManager::SetLevelCommand(char* command) const;
void CommandManager::SetPKCommand(char* command) const;
void CommandManager::SetZenCommand(char* command) const;
```

All this functions share the same structure

```
void CommandManager::SetZenCommand(char* command) const
{
    if (!IsUserAuthenticated(SET_ZEN))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!IsEnabled(SET_ZEN))
    {
        show error message about disabled command
    }

    if (strlen(command) < 1 || strlen(command) > 22)
    {
        show error message about usage of command
    }

    if (CountWhiteSpace(command) != 2)
    {
        show error message about wrong operation
    }
    ....
    some unique code from this function
    ...
}

void CommandManager::SetPKCommand(char* command) const
{
    if (!IsUserAuthenticated(SET_PK))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!IsEnabled(SET_PK))
    {
        show error message about disabled command
    }

    if (strlen(command) < 1 || strlen(command) > 13)
    {
        show error message about usage of command
    }

    if (CountWhiteSpace(command) != 2)
    {
        show error message about wrong operation
    }
     ....
     some unique code from this function
     ...
```

I created a map of errors and warning, to make the messages more easy to modify.

```
errorList[LEVEL] = ...

errorList[ZEN] = ...

errorList[DISABLED] = ...

errorList[WRONG_OPERATION] = ..

errorList[SET_PK_USAGE] = ...

errorList[SET_ZEN_USAGE] =  ...

errorList[NAME_LENGTH] = ...

errorList[CHARACTER_NOT_FOUND] = ...
```

It's possible to simplify this code ?
I mean modify the functions to make it more generic and reuse code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the obvious structure would be to write a `validate` function that each of the others calls to validate its input:

```
bool validate(std::string const &command, int val) { 
    if (!IsUserAuthenticated(val))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!IsEnabled(val))
    {
        // show error message about disabled command
        return false;
    }

    if (command.empty() || command.size() > *max_lens.find(val))
    {
        // show error message about usage of command
        return false;
    }

    if (CountWhiteSpace(command) != 2)
    {
        // show error message about wrong operation
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then each of the other functions would start by validating its input:

```
void CommandManager::SetPKCommand(std::string const &command) const
{
    if (!validate(command, SET_PK))
        return;
     // unique code from this function
}
```

A few other notes:

1. As shown above, `std::string` is *generally* preferred over a C-style string. If this were a performance-intensive part of the code, you might want to reconsider that, but that seems quite unlikely (at least to me).
2. I've assumed the existence of an `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`) named `max_lens` that we can use to look up the maximum length of any particular command. I strongly prefer this over spreading magic numbers throughout the code.
3. I've left the `2` in for the moment, but that *should* probably be replaced with something more meaningful as well.
4. You might want to consider having `validate` throw exceptions instead of returning a `bool` and (at least according to the comments) printing error messages (which really should be handled separately).

Comment: Think you need a `return true` in your validate function (but your answer is more complete than mine).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the correct site to ask about incomplete code. Nonetheless, here's an approach you can take.

```
bool CommandManager::ValidateCommand(const char* command, int set_type) const
{
    if (!IsUserAuthenticated(set_type))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!IsEnabled(set_type))
    {
        std::cout << "disabled: " << command << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (strlen(command) < 1 || strlen(command) > 22)
    {
        std::cout << "bad command len[1,22]: " << command << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (CountWhiteSpace(command) != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "bad command whitespace: " << command << std::endl;
        return false;    
    }

    return true;
}


void CommandManager::SetZenCommand(char* command) const
{
    if(!ValidateCommand(command, SET_ZEN)){
        return
    }
    ....
    some unique code from this function
    ...
}

void CommandManager::SetPkCommand(char* command) const
{
    if(!ValidateCommand(command, SET_PK)){
        return
    }
    ....
    some unique code from this function
    ...
}
```

Without more actual code - it's harder to advise further.